# Read datarow from the middle of the rows 101-200 of the dataset

Tags: .net, dataset, datarow

As i am having large dataset , to read that i am using threads.
 I want to read first 1-100 rows by creating new thread.
 and at the same time I want to read 101-200 by creating other thread.

I want to start both the threads at the same time.

Now the problem is how to read the dataset directly from 101-200 rows.It should directly point to 101 record.

Is there any way to do that...kindly help.

Thank you
Ramesh.T.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Enumerable.Skip with a DataTable.

You want records 101 - 200, so skip 100 records and get next 100 records.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = table.AsEnumerable().Skip(100).Take(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer will probably depend on the database used, but most have a LIMIT clause that can be used to start at result X and return Y results. So for example in mysql: select * from table LIMIT 101,100;

Comment: cant we read from certain point (101) in the dataset after all the records are returned from whatever the database is.Otherwise wha would be the best solution to read the large number of records from dataset instaed of looping all the rows row by row to make the performance fast.